# Why are these two DateTime instances different?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Consider the following (simplified) code:

```
DateTime now   = DateTime.Now;
DateTime now2  = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day,
                              now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second,
                              now.Millisecond, now.Kind);
bool condition = (now <= now2);
```

Since I've copied the fields of `now` to `now2`, these two instances of the `DateTime` structure should be equal. However, `condition` evaluates to `false`. Why?

Is there some way that I can change the code so that condition evaluates to true?

Comment: When you say "should be", do you mean that you put in a breakpoint and confirmed that the instances are in fact identical?

Comment: The debugger is your friend here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All answers correctly reported that problem is in ticks that are 10.000 times smaller than milliseconds, but didn't gave me an answer how to change condition so it evaluates to true. In my application, I must use constructor

```cs
DateTime(int year, int month, ...);
```

for now2 variable instead of:

```cs
DateTime(long ticks);
```

because of some business logic in application. It turns out that with first constructor it is not possible to set 10.000th part of milliseconds, and with second constructor it is not possible to set day of month without manually calculating some arithmetic. My solution is to use first constructor and add 1 millisecond before comparison:

```cs
DateTime now   = DateTime.Now;
DateTime now2  = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day,
                              now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second,
                              now.Millisecond, now.Kind);
bool condition = (now <= now2.AddMilliseconds(1));
```

Answer (score 7):

[It's the Ticks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx). It's always the Ticks. Sometimes.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime now2 = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day,
    now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second, now.Millisecond);
bool condition = (now <= now2);

var diff = now2 - now;
```

[image]

The time resolution is finer than milliseconds. [`Ticks` is the real value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 (0:00:00 UTC on January 1, 0001, in the Gregorian calendar), which represents DateTime.MinValue.

And there's a constructor for it:

```
var reallyNow = new Datetime(now.Ticks);
```

You never passed any value for `Ticks` into that constructor for `now2` (because it has no parameter for that), and so `now2.Ticks` will have four zeroes at the end. However `DateTime.Now`, which you copied directly to `now`, did have a `Ticks` value that wasn't evenly divisible by 10,000.

Comment: I thought that link at the beginning of your answer would be to some kind of hilarious meme. How disappointing.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the Ticks. Here Condition is true:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var now2 = new DateTime(now.Ticks);
var eq = now <= now2;
```

EDIT: answer to the question in comments:

```
var tempNow = DateTime.Now;
var now = new DateTime(tempNow.Year ...);
var now2 = new DateTime(tempNow.Year, tempNow.Month, customDay, ...)
```

in this case you can compare them as you want.

Comment: I need to set day of month differently from original date. Logic is working unless that day of month is today. How can I set day of month and keeping the rest of the DateTime?

Comment: @Uros Your code isn't working even when the day *isn't* today.  You're losing up to a millisecond of time in all of those other cases, you just didn't notice.

Comment: @Uros Is it what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Because the [resolution of DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) is 100 nanoseconds, not 1 millisecond. You only copied the values up to the millisecond.

> Time values are measured in 100-nanosecond units called ticks, [...]

Thus, you need to use a constructor which allows more precision than 1 millisecond, for example, [the constructor accepting "ticks"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime now2 = new DateTime(now.Ticks);
bool condition = (now <= now2);         // yields true
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Can I change day of month for now2?

Comment: @Uros: Sure, just use `AddDays` and a bit of math.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime has a lower resolution than milliseconds: ticks. When you create now2 the least significant digits in now2.Ticks are zero, that's why now2 is lesser than now.

For me:
now.Ticks = 636335767998991455
now2.Ticks = 636335767998990000

If you want to duplicate now to now2 use `DateTime now2 = new DateTime(now.Ticks)`

Comment: I would like to duplicate everything except day of month. Day of month is read from another variable. Can I set it somehow?